# Add real numers from user input assembly

Tags: linux, assembly

I am trying to create a calculator for a homework, but when I try to add the same number y throws me an error (Segmentation fault (`core' generado)) but when I show it there isn't problem. I am reserving the variable opcion for a double precision number. My question is if I have to make a conversion of the user input to a number or I can just add it. I read about the FPU but i don't know exactly how to use it.

The calculator already does the basic operations (+,-,*,/,%) but does it with integers.

```
%include    'funciones32.asm'
SECTION     .data
    a       dd  5
SECTION     .bss
    opcion: resq    1
SECTION     .text
    global  _start
    _start:
        mov     eax, 3
        mov     ebx, 0
        mov     ecx, opcion
        mov     edx, 8
        int     80H
        mov     eax, opcion
        call    print
        mov     eax, opcion
        mov     ebx, opcion
        fadd    eax, ebx
        call    print
        call    quit
```

I am working in linux 32 bits.

Comment: Yes you will of course need to convert it. You also need to convert it for integer arithmetic (but differently), if it works you surely have done that. Note you are definitely **not running the code as shown** since `fadd eax, ebx` does not even assemble so there is nothing you could run to produce a segfault. Please always post the exact code you are testing with. See also [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, the correct operation es "add eax, ebx". Thanks for the link.